# Position the legend outside the plot area with Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, legend, bokeh

I am making a plot following the example found [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html)

Unfortunately, I have 17 curves I need to display, and the legend overlaps them. I know I can create a legend object that can be displayed outside the plot area like [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#outside-the-plot-area), but I have 17 curves so using a loop is much more convenient.

Do you know how to combine both methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. See the code below where I have just modified the interactive legend example:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime", toolbar_location='above')
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to mute the corresponding lines'

legend_it = []

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    c = p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8,
           muted_color=color, muted_alpha=0.2)
    legend_it.append((name, [c]))


legend = Legend(items=legend_it)
legend.click_policy="mute"

p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

show(p)
```

Comment: after some attempts I ended up with the exact same logic as @Despe1990 ... how can it be this the "best" way of putting the legend box outside the plot frame? I would have imagined that a negative position coordinate would have made the trick, but it does not. it just makes disappear the legend from the output ... that's something bokeh should would on!

Comment: I found out using location=(10, 60) works better for me. I use my figures in a column layout and (0, -60) made the legend to be partially visible.

Answer (score 18):

I'd like to expand on joelostbloms answer.
It is also possible to pull out the legend from an existing plot and add it
somewhere else after the plot has been created.

```
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers


# add a column with colors to the data
colors = dict(zip(flowers['species'].unique(), Category10[10]))
flowers["color"] = [colors[species] for species in flowers["species"]]

# make plot
p = figure(height=350, width=500)
p.circle("petal_length", "petal_width", source=flowers, legend_group='species',
         color="color")
p.add_layout(p.legend[0], 'right')

show(p)
```

Comment: 'Pull out the legend and put it somewhere else', this idea is awesome!

Answer (score 10):

It is also possible to place legends outside the plot areas for auto-grouped, indirectly created legends. The trick is to create an empty legend and use `add_layout` to place it outside the plot area before using the glyph `legend_group` parameter:

```py
from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper, Legend
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers


color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(
    factors=[x for x in flowers['species'].unique()], palette=Category10[10])
p = figure(height=350, width=500)
p.add_layout(Legend(), 'right')
p.circle("petal_length", "petal_width", source=flowers, legend_group='species',
         color=dict(field='species', transform=color_mapper))
show(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A note on visibility as the above answers, while useful, didn't see me successfully place the legend below the plot and others may come across this too.

Where the plot_height or height are set for the figure as so:

```
p = figure(height=400)
```

But the legend is created as in Despee1990's answer and then placed below the plot as so:

```
legend = Legend(items=legend_it)
p.add_layout(legend, 'below')
```

Then the legend is not displayed, nor the plot.

If the location is changed to the right:

```
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')
```

...then the legend is only displayed where the items fit within the figure plot height. I.e. if you have a plot height of 400 but the legend needs a height of 800 then you won't see the items that don't fit within the plot area.

To resolve this either remove the plot height from the figure entirely or specify a height sufficient to include the height of the legend items box.

i.e. either:

```
p = figure()
```

or if Legend required height = 800 and glyph required height is 400:

```
p = figure(plot_height=800)
p.add_layout(legend, 'below')
```