# Adding legend outside the bokeh plot

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, bokeh

I am adding lines to **bokeh plot**. I am using following code

```
for line in lines:
      figure.line(x='x',y='y',source=source,legend='some_name',color='some_color')
```

I want to place legend outside the box in above case how can i do it?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#outside-the-plot-area?

Comment: yes . We can access leged by using figure.legend object. How can we place such legend outside the plot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

Comment: you can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730609/position-the-legend-outside-the-plot-area-with-bokeh

Comment: still bokeh here is being very unfriendly. would it be enough to ask for the legend on a negative coordinate, but it's not working like that ...