# Add Label Annotations on Axes

Tags: python, bokeh

I currently annotate my charts with the last value of each series by adding a `Label` and supplying my the name of corresponding range it's plotted on:

```
Label(
    ...
    x=data.index.max(),
    y=data.loc[data.index.max(), 'my_col'],
    y_range_name='my_range'
    ...
)
```

Which gives me:

[image: section of line chart on multiple axes, with text annotations of each series' last value]

How do I move the labels so they are positioned on their respective axis?
Example:

[image]

Please note that my labels' y-positioning is off, so I need some help with that aspect too. I've tried tweaking the `y_offset` but this has not yielded any consistently good results.
My data are always numerical time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.2 there is no built-in annotation or glyph that will display outside the central plot area. There is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5724) that this is similar to that you can follow or comment on. For the time being, something like this would require making a [custom extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html)

Comment: Where in that GitHub issue discussion does it state the inability to have an annotation outside of the plot area?

Comment: It doesn't explicitly, but I regard it as related to that, because a precursor to having tooltips that "stick" is having an API for programmatically placing tooltips. Placing them outside the axes would be a small (reasonable) leap from there, but you are correct it is not explicitly stated.  Your comments, input there would be helpful.

Comment: I don't want a tool tip, just the Label. So all in SVG space. Guess I will have to stick with what I have. Thanks. Any idea why the y-position is off?

Comment: Never mind, it was user error on the y position stuff. I wasn't being specific enough when filtering nans.

Comment: OK FWIW the image you have of the thing over the axis is what I consider (and would be implemented wit) hover tooltips. Glad you have it sorted out, regardless!

Comment: I've just [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46731430/745808) which I've used to place labels over the axis like i wanted. However, the resulting "view box" sometimes isn't wide enough and the labels get clipped. Is there a way to auto size this view so the labels are always visible?

Comment: Actually, using `x_units='screen'` is also giving inconsistent results. Do you have any tips? I feel like I'm so close.

Comment: SO is not a good place for iterative discussion in general, and in the comments is even worse. I also definitely don't have suggestions without a minimal example of code you are starting from that can be tried out and  experimented with. I'd suggest moving this to the project Discourse https://discourse.bokeh.org

Comment: Hi @bigreddot, I'm trying to accomplish the same thing, two years have been past, is there any updates ? if not, could you give me some hint how to use custom extension to display LabelSet on axis ticks out side the plot box?