# How to plot LabelSet outside the plot box?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm trying to highlight last value of a time series plot by plot its value on yaxis, as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837190/add-label-annotations-on-axes). I prefer using LabelSet over Legend because you can precisely control the text positions and also using a data source to update it. But unfortunately, I can not find out how to draw label text outside the plot box.

Here is some code to plot LabelSet and notice how the text is only shown inside the box (66.1x is partially blocked by yaxis):

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import LabelSet, ColumnDataSource
#import bokeh.sampledata
#bokeh.sampledata.download()
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

p = figure(
    x_axis_type="datetime", width=1000, toolbar_location='left',
    title = "MSFT Candlestick", y_axis_location="right")

p.line(df.date, df.close)
ds = ColumnDataSource({'x': [df.date.iloc[-1]], 'y': [df.close.iloc[-1]], 'text': ['  ' + str(df.close.iloc[-1])]})
ls = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='text', source=ds)
p.add_layout(ls)

show(p)
```

[image]
Please let me know how to show LabelSet outside the box, Thanks

Comment: You could create little space in graph?

Comment: yes, I could, but that's not what i want. what I want is to plot labelset on top of yaxis ticks, the example just demonstrate i can not do that.