# How to work with ColumnDataSource and LegendItem together in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to create a categorial scatter plot with these functions using bokeh:

1. Hover Tooltips
2. Legend outside the plot area with click policy = "hide"

After numerous searches, I can implement the function #1 and #2 separately.

***But I don't know how to make these 2 functions work at the same time.***

***Tooltips only needs one glyph object, but legend outside plot area needs a for-loop to create a list of glyph objects which is used to generate legend_items.***

Thanks.

Code Example:

1. Hover Tooltips can be achieved by using ColumnDataSources
   (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#heat-maps)

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

df = pd.DataFrame(AAPL)
output_file("test.html")
p = figure(tools="hover")
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p.scatter("high", "low", source=source)

p.hover.tooltips = [("Date","@date")]

show(p)
```

2. Legend outside the plot
   ([Position the legend outside the plot area with Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730609/position-the-legend-outside-the-plot-area-with-bokeh))

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.models import Legend, LegendItem
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, GOOG, IBM, MSFT

output_file("test2.html")
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
p_list = []

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    p_list.append(p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8))

legend_items = [LegendItem(label=x, renderers=[p_list[i]]) for i, x in enumerate(["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"])]
legend_ = Legend(items=legend_items, click_policy="hide", location="center", label_text_font_size="12px")
p.add_layout(legend_, "right")

show(p)
```

Comment: You can add tools as instances instead of strings. `HoverTool` accept `renderers` just as well as `LegendItem` does.

Comment: With that being said, I still don't understand why you cannot just add the hover tool to the second example. Just specify `tools='hover'` in the call to `figure`.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov thanks for the comment. I am not sure if the tooltips can map to the dataframe without calling the ColumnDataSource.  I would like to show specific columns with respect to the data in the same row. Adding ```tools='hover'``` just gave me tooltips of the x, y and the index.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Yes, you have to use `ColumnDataSource` to be able to use data columns. Let my try to come up with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.models import Legend, LegendItem, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, GOOG, IBM, MSFT

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools='hover')
p.hover.tooltips = [("Date", "@date{%F}"),
                    ("Open", "@open"),
                    ("Close", "@close")]
p.hover.formatters = {'@date': 'datetime'}

legend_items = []
for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG],
                             ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"],
                             Spectral4):
    data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).values
    ds = ColumnDataSource(data)
    renderer = p.line('date', 'close', source=ds,
                      line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8)
    legend_items.append(LegendItem(label=name, renderers=[renderer]))

legend = Legend(items=legend_items, click_policy="hide",
                location="center", label_text_font_size="12px")
p.add_layout(legend, "right")

show(p)
```

If you want to have different tooltips for different stocks, you can create one hover tool per each stock and specify them in the `tools` argument. The downside - there will be multiple hover tool buttons on the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This provides me some idea, although it does not apply to my plot. I have a large dataset, so the plots went empty after using your idea.

Comment: It's impossible to tell anything without the actual code, Python errors, and JavaScript errors in your browser.

Comment: yea I understand. The code is almost the same as yours, I just changed the ```p.line()``` into ```p.x()```.  The dimension of the DataFrame is (700k,6). With the for loop of the ```ColumnDataSource```, the html size have increased into 80MB from 15MB. I can only see the grid of the plot, and I can see the correct tooltips information when my cursor stayed on the 'invisible' points. I think it should be kind of out-of-memory.